# Data Management Error C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, memory-management

I am having difficulties with my code. The issue is that even though my program runs all the way through, it still crashes at the end. My IDE gives me no disapproval and there is no indicator as to why my program is failing right at the end, so I am led to believe there is something going out of bounds or something messing up my stack. I have looked through my code and nothing appears to be out of bounds, so I am entirely confused on this matter.

I am using a header file I created, a file to contain my functions from the header file, and a main method file. The error is a result of the file containing my functions.

The fields of my class are
size - int

low - int

high - int

windowSize - int

*filteredArray - int

array[] - int

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef FILTER_HPP_
#define FILTER_HPP_
#include<iostream>


class Filter {
    int size;
    int high;
    int low;
    int windowSize;
    int *filteredArray;
    int array[];
    public:
        // Constructor
        Filter(int windowSize);
        // Methods
        void randArrayGen();
        int* randArrayGenRecurHelper(int arrayRecur[], int count);
        void randArrayGenRecur();
        void printArrays();
        int hanning(int ar[]);
        void hanningFilter();
        void graphicArrays();
        int getSize();
        int getHigh();
        int getLow();

};





#endif /* FILTER_HPP_ */
```

Here is the code:

```
#include "Filter.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

// Constructor
Filter::Filter(int num){
    size = ((rand() % 25) + 25);
    high = ((rand() % 6) + 5);
    low = ((rand() % 6) + 5) * -1;
    windowSize = num;
    randArrayGen();
    hanningFilter();

}


void Filter::randArrayGen(){
    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++){
        array[i] = (rand() % (high + low * -1)) + low;
    }
}




int Filter::hanning(int ar[]){
    int weightAvg;

    if(windowSize == 3){
        weightAvg = (ar[0] + ar[1] * 2 +ar[2]) / 4;
    }
    else if(windowSize == 5){
        weightAvg = (ar[0] + ar[1] * 2 + ar[2] * 3 + ar[3] * 2 + ar[4]) / 9;
    }
    else if(windowSize == 7){
        weightAvg = (ar[0] + ar[1] * 2 + ar[2] * 3 + ar[3] * 4 + ar[4] *3 + ar[5] * 2 + ar[6]) / 16;
    }
    else if(windowSize == 9){
            weightAvg = (ar[0] + ar[1] * 2 +ar[2] * 3 + ar[3] * 4 + ar[4] * 5 + ar[5] * 4 + ar[6] * 3 + ar[7] * 2 + ar[8]) / 25;
        }
    else{
        weightAvg = 0;
    }
    return weightAvg;
}



void Filter::hanningFilter(){
    filteredArray = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(i - (windowSize/2) < 0 or i + (windowSize/2) > size - 1){
            filteredArray[i] = 0;
        }
        else{
            filteredArray[i] = hanning(&array[i-(windowSize/2)]);
        }
    }
}



int Filter::getHigh(){
    return high;
}

int Filter::getLow(){
    return low;
}

int Filter::getSize(){
    return size;
}
```

Comment: How do you allocate `array`? Specifically the `new int[..what size..?]` line.

Comment: It would be nice if you gave a summary of what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: I checked through the code and found I haven't actually allocated it at all... It still works however.

Comment: This code is supposed to create a random array of size 25-50 with randomly set high and low values, and then run a hanning filter over it to create a filtered array.

Comment: "I haven't actually allocated it at all" - well, there's your problem! "It still works however" - this is mere luck (I'd call it bad luck) that it does, except for the hanging at the end bit.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That was actually the issue. I am both very frustrated that it still worked despite that error but glad I figured it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't allocate memory for your array:

```
int array[];
```

And when you index it like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size;i++){
    array[i] = (rand() % (high + low * -1)) + low;
}
```

you invoke *Undefined Behavior*, since you go out of bounds (you request the first element for example, but from an array of unknown size).

You could declare the array with a fixed size, like this for example:

```
int array[100];
```

---

However, since this is C++, consider using [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). An immediate advantage is that you don't have to hardcode a size for your statically allocated array, but you can rely on the vector's ability to resize as the data are inserted/pushed into it.

Comment: Or, since it's C++, use `std::vector array;` throughout.